# How to leave the rest of a page empty after inserting a figure in latex?

Tags: floats, afterpage, clearpage

I would like to insert a figure with its caption entirely in a page with the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}


\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
% Depending on your LaTeX fonts installation, you might get better results with one of these:
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}


% Only include extra packages if you really need them. Common packages are:
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Including figure files
\usepackage{relsize}          %To change the scale/size of the fonts
\usepackage{amsmath}    % Advanced maths commands
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{amssymb}   % Extra maths symbols

% Extra packages
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{afterpage}
%\usepackage{extarrows}

\title[]{Title of the Paper}

\author[First Author]{
First Author's name,$^{1}$\thanks{E-mail: author1@gmail.com}
Second Author's name,$^{2}$\thanks{E-mail: author2@gmail.com}
Third Author's name$^{2,3}$\thanks{E-mail: author3@gmail.com}
\\
$^{2}$The mailing address of the university in which 2nd author resides\\
$^{3}$The mailing address of the university in which 3rd author resides\\
$^{1}$The mailing address of the university in which 2nd author resides}






\date{Accepted XXX. Received YYY; in original form ZZZ}

\pubyear{2017}

\begin{document}
\label{firstpage}
\pagerange{\pageref{firstpage}--\pageref{lastpage}}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}


\begin{keywords}

\end{keywords}


\section{Convergence due to Resolution Effects}  \label{Appendix:Appendix C}

\begin{figure*}
     \includegraphics[height=9.5cm]{m12m_hist_high}
    \caption{the caption for 34th figure}
    \label{fig:Figure 34}
\end{figure*}


\begin{figure*}
       \includegraphics[height=9.5cm]{m11q_low_high}
    \caption{the caption for 42nd figure.}
    \label{fig:Figure 42}
\end{figure*}



\begin{figure*}
       \includegraphics[height=9.5cm]{m11q_local_high}
    \caption{the caption for 43rd figure}
    \label{fig:Figure 43}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
     \includegraphics[height=9.5cm]{m11q_hist_high}
    \caption{the caption for 53rd figure.}
    \label{fig:Figure 53}
\end{figure*}



\bsp    % typesetting comment
\label{lastpage}
\end{document}
```

However, I have other figures with different purpose starting after figure 34. So, I would like to start them over from a new page right after the this figure with no empty page in between but rather leave the rest of the previous page empty. I attempted to use the notation outside the first figure but that leaves me an entire empty page which is not desired.

Is there a way to remove the empty page between the two and instead leave the rest of the first page right after the first figure empty and start over from the next page?

Comment: a bit hard to say with no example but probably `\begin{figure*}[p]` is enough.  `\clearpage` (with or without `\afterpage`, which doesn't seem needed here) shouldn't force a blank page, so if it does, there is something you have not shown in the input.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please always add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)  that shows your problems. Such a MWE should start with `\documentclass` and contain a complete body from `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}`. This makes is much easier to reproduce and understand your problem and answer your question. Questions without code or with code snippets instead of MWEs are always somehow unclear.

Comment: Tried adding [p] but it did nothing. Added a MWE too.

Comment: The packages `ae` and `aecompl` have been obsolete for several years. Besides, loading them after `newtxtext` overrides it.

Comment: There are four figures in your MWE. Which one is the "this figure" that you refer to?  Using [p] as David says is the canonical answer, but perhaps this is disabled by mnras.cls which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: I meant first figure (34). And I deleted the obsolete packages ae and aecompl as suggested. But I still have problem. [p] doesn't work. But in my first use of \afterpage, the first figure (34) jumps to the next appendix which is not intended. And for my second use of \afterpage, I receive the error message "LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode".

Answer (score 2):

I have to follow these to arrive at a resolution:

(1)
Following the suggestion of egreg and deleting the packages `ae` and `aecompl` that are obsolete

(2)
Verifying the possibility that `mnras.cls` has disabled the option `[p]` following the suggestion of Peter Flynn

(3) 
Following the comment made by David Carlisle and trying `\clearpage` again without overwriting `newtxtext` package through inappropriate use of obsolete packages mentioned in (1) alone with no `\afterpage`,

(4)
And my own realization that there is no need of the command `\bst` at the end of the `.tex` file as it was forcing the creation of a completely empty page which is undesired.

I was able to resolve the issue finally. Thanks for everyone's contribution.